# Map is getting appended to modal-body for each button click: jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

**Summary**:

I am creating a web page which shows results of user selections. First user select items from the given panel and clicks on add button. This creates a table row of selected items of the user(Just like adding items to the cart). If the user selection contains "Map" then it creates a `#map` button in one of the created table columns.

I have created modal-dialog bootstrap for the map button. When user clicks it, map is popped up and it returns (lat,lon,zoom) parameters once "save" button is clicked from the modal-footer.

**Issue**:

If the user selects "Map" option more than once. The previous map is appending to the modal-body. and looks ugly.

Here is the jquery code for creating table.

```
 .on('click','.addbutton', function(e) {
    $('table').find('tbody')
        .each(function(){
            var map_elements = '<td style = "text-align:center">';
            if (display_text == 'Map') {
                map_elements += '<button data-target="#map_btn_benefits_id" type="button" class="map_btn_benefits btn btn-info active" data-toggle="modal">Map</button>';
                map_elements += '<div id="map_btn_benefits_id" class="modal fade" role="dialog">';
                map_elements += '<div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><h4 class="modal-title">Landscape Map</h4></div>';
                map_elements += '<div class="modal-body"><div id="map_id_benefits" style="width: 500px; height: 380px; margin: 0; padding: 0;"></div></div>';
                map_elements += '<div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="save-exit-benefits btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save changes and Close</button>';
                map_elements += '</div></div></div></div>';
                map_elements += '</td>';

            }   
            else {
                map_elements += display_text+'</td>';               
            }

            console.log(map_elements);
$(this).append(
        "<tr>"+
        "<td><a class='remove-row text-danger'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></a></td>"+
        "<td style='text-align:center'>"+tree_benefits_text+"</td>"+
        map_elements+
        "<td style='text-align:center'>"+unit_text+"</td>"+
        "<td style='text-align:center'>"+dataset_text+"</td>"+
        "</tr>")
```

Below is the script for creating map

```
.on('click', '.map_btn_benefits', function(){

    var ml = new googleMap({element: 'map_id_benefits'});       
    var save_selection_layer= [];
    $('.save-exit-benefits').click(function () {
        save_selection_benefits.push(
        {
            lon_map: ml.map.getCenter().lon,
            lat_map: ml.map.getCenter().lat,
            zoom_map: ml.map.getZoom(),
        });   
        
    });

    console.log(save_selection_benefits);
})
```

Assume "googleMap()" creates a simple map. I believe for this question you do not need code for it.
I apologize for my bad explanation. I am new to jquery.
I am looking for logic i am missing here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: try to empty the map container before loading new instance of map. $('map_id_benefits').empty()

Comment: @LokeshYadav Thank you i will try that but will this effect "save_selection_benefits" values. because i need those each values in next steps

Comment: create a global variable, lets called it (mapon) and set it to (var mapon = "no"). when a user clicks the show map option, show the map and set the (mapon = "yes"). In your function to show the map if (mapon == "yes) skip the part that displays the map on the canvas and simply clear the marker and add a new one using the lon,lat coordinates. this way you are only dealing with one map. If you find it difficult to do that using Gmaps API, then you can try Gmaps JS https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/ as it has all the options to do all that easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked by emptying the modal container

```
$('map_id_benefits').empty()
```